# Rendering html in Angular with Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, compiler-directives

I am storing html data in my database from the output of a WYSIWYG editor. The html also stores the html for some directives. One of them being the ui-bootstrap tooltip:

```
<span tooltip-placement="left" tooltip="On the Left!">Tooltip text here</span>
```

I am able to get any other html elements to work by using the binding:

```
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="html.content"></div>
```

But the html with the directive's reference doesn't interact with the actual directive.

How can I get the directive to work?

Do I have to compile the html or something like that?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, since the markup you are trying to render contains directives, you need to compile it so they are processed by Angular.

You could create a directive that does that for you:

```
app.directive('htmlRender', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: { html: '@' },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      scope.$watch('html', function(value) {
        if (!value) return;

        var markup = $compile(value)(scope);
        element.append(markup);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/2HtkzGkLdjcZDWGg0BDN?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

```
Do I have to compile the html or something like that?
```

Yes You need to complile the HTML as Angular will only consider as below as simple html

```
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="html.content"></div>
```

Check below is documentation for $compile

[$complie documenation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile)

Comment: I managed to make a simple directive that compiles the html value that it is given, and then simply places that content within the element - the compile documentation was very useful in this regard